# How to set Exposed Dropdown Menus' start value?

Tags: android, material-design

Failing to set the start value of the newly introduced exposed dropdown menu.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#exposed-dropdown-menus

I am trying to get the first value set but when I try to use the "selectedItemPosition" I am getting an error, that those attribute has not been found.

Also, trying to achieve this with java code, gave me an error, that there is no index.

```java
// Trying to set it via java code
Binding.dropdownSex.setAdapter(getAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fragment_me_spinner_sex)));
        mBinding.dropdownSex.setSelection(1);   // java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (1 ... 1) ends beyond length 0 


// just a small method to get the adapter
private ArrayAdapter<String> getAdapter(String[] elements) {
        return new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),
                R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item,
                elements);
    }
```

also...

```xml
<!-- attribute android:selectedItemPosition not found. -->
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                >

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/dropdown_sex"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/sex"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
```

Someone an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am also facing this.

Answer (score 2):

Try below after set adapter method

```
dropdown_sex.setText(loadCenterList.get(mViewFlipper.displayedChild - 1), false)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mBinding.dropdownSex.setText(*TEXT OF ARRAY ITEM HERE*);`